# Call to method from Parent Abstract Class

Tags: java, interface, abstract-class, overriding

I was just trying to understand the abstract classes and interfaces in detail with java.
I have read few questions in SO related to overriding and implementing same signature method from abstract class and interface together.

References: [One](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296789/same-method-in-interface-and-abstract-class), [Two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11434137/interface-and-abstract-class-ad-method-overriding)

After that I just tried with my own code to learn the concept more clearly.
Then I came across few questions:

1. How will I call the concrete method written in Abstract class ?
2. Will the type casting is possible between `A` and `I`, if the object is of type `C` ?

I have tried with the below code:

```
public class TestMethods {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    C c1 = new C();
    c1.methodOne();
    c1.methodTwo();

    // Q.1
    A c2 = new C();
    // HOW TO CALL METHOD IN CLASS A WITH c2
    c2.methodOne(); // I want to call here methodOne() from A

    // Q.2
    I c3 = new C();
    A c4 = (A) c3;
    // WILL THIS TYPE CASTING WORKS
    // HOW TO CALL METHOD IN CLASS A WITH c4
    c4.methodOne();
    c4.methodTwo();
  }

}

class C extends A implements I{

  @Override
  public void methodTwo() {
    System.out.println("Method Two in Concrete Class C");
  }

  @Override
  public void methodOne(){
    System.out.println("Method One in Concrete Class C");
  }

}


abstract class A{
  public void methodOne(){
    System.out.println("Method One in Abstract Class A");
  }

  public abstract void methodTwo();
}

interface I{
  public void methodOne();
  public void methodTwo();
}
```

**ADDED**

Q.3
As per the suggestion in one of the answers below, I can call `super.methodOne()` from class `C`. But what if I do not have a call to super from my concrete class `C` to call concrete method from its extending parent abstract class `A` ? And I do not want the modification to my concrete class `C`, then will I be able to call the method in super class ?

Comment: I have tried with some code and asked the questions for which I didn't found any answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. you can call the concrete method with `super.methodOne()`
2. you can cast C to A and C to I, not the other way around since C has everything that A has but can have some more, so C is A but A is NOT C.

Comment: For Q.1 - from where should I call this `super.methodOne()`, because I want to call after I have created the `c2` object. I tried with calling `((A)c2).methodOne()` but it still calls the method from `C`.

For Q.2 My question was, Can I be able to cast reference of `I` to reference of `A`, if the object is of type `C`.

Comment: 1. you can call `super.methodOne()` from any place inside class C.
2. yes you can, but only if you sure its an object of type A or C.

Comment: Ok. I tried adding `public void methodSuper(){  super.methodOne(); }` inside `C` and calling this `methodSuper()` from my main, but as I am using reference of `A` I was not allowed to call `methodSuper()` even though the object is of type `C`.

Comment: the reference type is not important during runtime.