# Java - class extending abstract class and implementing an interface having same methods

Tags: java, oop, interface, abstract-class

like in topic. Here's an example:

```
public abstract class Bird{
   public abstract void eat();
   public abstract void fly();
}


public interface Flyable{
    public void fly();
}

public class Test extends Bird implements Flyable{
   public void eat(){
      System.out.println("I'm eating");
   }

   // And what's now?
   public void fly(){

   }
}
```

And now, there is main question. What happens. Is an error being throwed, or fly is same for interface and abstract class?

Comment: You can implement that method. No error is thrown. Please see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296789/same-method-in-interface-and-abstract-class

Answer (score 2):

Nothing happens. Just implement your logic inside `fly()` and be happy.

Answer (score 2):

If the methods have the same signature, everything will be fine. It is also okay to have the implementation in the abstract class or to implement a method which is specified in multiple interfaces of the class.

In Java, a method is identified by its name and its parameters. Consequently, the **return type** of the implemented method **must be compatible** with all return types of all specified methods with the same identifier. The same applies to the **throw clauses.** If the return type or throw clauses of the implemented method are incompatible, you will get a compilation error.

This example is not working:

```
public interface Flyable {
  void eat();
  void fly();
}

public abstract class Bird {
  public int eat() {
    return 500;
  }

  public void fly() throws StallException {
  }
}

public class Eagle extends Bird implements Flyable {
}
```

> `Eagle.java`, line `1`: Exception `StallException` in throws clause of `Bird.fly()` is not compatible with `Flyable.fly()`
>
> `Eagle.java`, line `1`: The return types are incompatible for the inherited methods `Flyable.eat()`, `Bird.eat()`