# extends vs implements visibility in child class

Tags: java, jmockit

```
public interface A{
  public void doSomething();
}

public abstract class B{
  public void doSomething(){
    //implementation...
    }
  }

public abstract class C extends B implements A{
}

public class D extends C{
... //doSomething() is not overriden 
}
```

This compiles without problem, also when an instance of D calls the method doSomething().

But jmockit gives error when the method is called from an instance of D and the method is not overriden in D. Please explain this behaviour.

Comment: Related [Same method in Interface and Abstract class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11296789/same-method-in-interface-and-abstract-class).

Comment: I think you should include enough code to reproduce the error. This is perfectly legal java, so the question is more about how jmockit works.

Comment: I don't see a problem. The interface `A` says "*hey `D`, you need a `doSomething` method*". But it has, since it's extending from `B` which provides an implementation.

Comment: Also this has nothing to do with generics so you can remove that tag.

Comment: in our implementation it is with generics... that is why i included this tag. 
then would it make a difference when the abstract class and interface is with Generics?

Comment: Depends on the exact scenario. If the interface wants a method that operates on `String` while your method from `B` operates on `Integer`, then the methods are different and you miss the implementation for the `String` variant.

Comment: I can not reproduce the error with code you post...

Comment: Its like Interface A<T, Long>   abstract class B<T exteds X , Long>     and.    abstract class C<T extends X, Long>     and   class D<T extends X, Long>

Comment: Please show an example test. Without it, there is no way anyone can begin to investigate the issue. We don't even know which class, if any, is supposed to be mocked...

Comment: The class D is mocked... And in expectations Block
 {DInstance.doSomething(); result =xyz;}    class X is being tested which had D as member.

Answer (score 0):

found the solution. what i didnt mention was that we were using jmockit version 1.30, since i didnt think that would be the issue. This issue was aparently fixed in higher versions.

https://github.com/jmockit/jmockit1/issues/389